# CSS is refusing to update

Tags: html, css, wamp, sublimetext3, wampserver

My computer is having an error where the CSS stops working. For example before, when I modify the CSS and save it, it would work on the webpage and all would be fine.

Now however, if I edit and save the CSS the webpage does not change at all, its almost as if the CSS is stuck in a cached version or something.

I  am using sublime text 3, wamp server and chrome.

Anyone have any ideas on what the error could be?

Comment: Try CTRL + SHIFT + R to do hard refresh in your browser.

Comment: Seems to have worked, thank you sir! and idea why this would happen now? I have been using this setup for over a year.

Comment: If you use this key combination it forces the browser to reload the page without using the files in cache. So obviously your css file was cached and your browser didn't show the update, because there were none in the cached file. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

This will hard refresh your browser. This command helps you to clear the browser's cache for a specific page.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting images and files in cache.
Then you can also use a *workaround* if it's a cache problem: you can add a get version parameter to your css src when you include it, and upgrade the parameter.
For instance:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your/src?v=0.1">
```

Then if you modify the css, you can change the **v** value

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your/src?v=0.2">
```

Without have to delete cache or something else

Answer (score 0):

Close your files in text editor and open again your files in text editor.Recheck the file address you want to open in wamp server or open again.